# LibStreaming gives black screen when change resolution

Tags: android, video-streaming, streaming, rtsp

I have using spydroid from https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera.
Based on the requirement streaming should be send and receive in the device. from local network we should able to shown the rtsp stream. Ex. VLC Media Player.

The issue I am facing is, When I am change the resolution Ex. 640*480. It should give black screen with streaming live. In Default demo, It should support 320*240, which is working fine. I have also change the bitrate and framerate according to 640*480 resolution. But couldn't get the result.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using old library which the demo **SpyDroid** is using.

I had same issue with the code i tried following way :-

Steps:-

1.)include library [LibStreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) .

- As it is the latest library and supporting above Lollipop version.

2.)Find [H263Stream](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/video/H264Stream.java) **class**  Change following method :-

**From**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private MP4Config testMediaCodecAPI() throws RuntimeException, IOException {
    createCamera();
    updateCamera();
    try {
        if (mQuality.resX>=640) {
            // Using the MediaCodec API with the buffer method for high resolutions is too slow
            mMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API;
        }
        EncoderDebugger debugger = EncoderDebugger.debug(mSettings, mQuality.resX, mQuality.resY);
        return new MP4Config(debugger.getB64SPS(), debugger.getB64PPS());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Fallback on the old streaming method using the MediaRecorder API
        Log.e(TAG,"Resolution not supported with the MediaCodec API, we fallback on the old streamign method.");
        mMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API;
        return testH264();
    }
```

}

**To**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private MP4Config testMediaCodecAPI() throws RuntimeException, IOException {
    createCamera();
    updateCamera();
    try {
        if (mQuality.resX>=1080) {
            // Using the MediaCodec API with the buffer method for high resolutions is too slow
            mMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API;
        }
        EncoderDebugger debugger = EncoderDebugger.debug(mSettings, mQuality.resX, mQuality.resY);
        return new MP4Config(debugger.getB64SPS(), debugger.getB64PPS());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Fallback on the old streaming method using the MediaRecorder API
        Log.e(TAG,"Resolution not supported with the MediaCodec API, we fallback on the old streamign method.");
        mMode = MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API;
        return testH264();
    }
}
```

-You can find the difference change resolution from "**640**" into "**1080**"

-Don't know what exact reason is but above solution worked for me.

-Revert me back if there is any loop fall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in MediaRecorder:
file: VideoStream.java
method: encodeWithMediaRecorder

MediaRecorder doesn't support ParcelFileDescriptor correctly.  I created local file to save stream form MediaRecorder:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.tmpFileToStream);
//mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fd); //disable..
```

and then I run new thread to copy bytes from tmpFileToStream to mParcelWrite

```
public void run()
{
    FileDescriptor fd = mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor();

    try {
        InputStream isS = new FileInputStream(tmpFileToStream); //read from local file..

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fd);

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

            int content;
            while ((content = isS.read()) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(content);
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "E.. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Video encoding is done by a MediaRecorder.
 */
protected void encodeWithMediaRecorder() throws IOException, ConfNotSupportedException {

    Log.d(TAG,"Video encoded using the MediaRecorder API");
    Log.d(TAG,"Roz" + mRequestedQuality.resX + " x " +  mRequestedQuality.resY + " frame " + mRequestedQuality.framerate );

    // We need a local socket to forward data output by the camera to the packetizer
    createSockets();

    // Reopens the camera if needed
    destroyCamera();
    createCamera();

    // The camera must be unlocked before the MediaRecorder can use it
    unlockCamera();


     this.tmpFileToStream = this.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    Log.d(TAG,"Video record to " + this.tmpFileToStream.getAbsolutePath() );

    try {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
//      mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(mVideoEncoder);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mRequestedQuality.resX,mRequestedQuality.resY);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mRequestedQuality.framerate);

        // The bandwidth actually consumed is often above what was requested 
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate((int)(mRequestedQuality.bitrate*0.8));



        // We write the output of the camera in a local socket instead of a file !          
        // This one little trick makes streaming feasible quiet simply: data from the camera
        // can then be manipulated at the other end of the socket
        FileDescriptor fd = null;
        if (sPipeApi == PIPE_API_PFD) {
            fd = mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor();

        } else  {
            fd = mSender.getFileDescriptor();
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.tmpFileToStream);  //save to local.. afeter read and stream that..
    //  mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fd); //disable..


        // copy bytes from local file to mParcelWrite.. :)
        if(tInput == null) {
            this.tInput = new Thread(this);
            this.tInput.start();
        }

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();


    } catch (Exception e) {


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);

        Log.d(TAG, "Error stack " + sw.toString());

        throw new ConfNotSupportedException(e.getMessage());
    }



    InputStream is = null;

    if (sPipeApi == PIPE_API_PFD) {
        is = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(mParcelRead);
    } else  {
        is = mReceiver.getInputStream();
    }



    // This will skip the MPEG4 header if this step fails we can't stream anything :(
    try {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4];
        // Skip all atoms preceding mdat atom
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            while (is.read() != 'm');
            is.read(buffer,0,3);
            if (buffer[0] == 'd' && buffer[1] == 'a' && buffer[2] == 't') break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Couldn't skip mp4 header :/");
        stop();
        throw e;
    }

    // The packetizer encapsulates the bit stream in an RTP stream and send it over the network
    mPacketizer.setInputStream(is);
    mPacketizer.start();

    mStreaming = true;

}
```

That's unusual solution but it works for another resolution